# Silverlight 3: iteration order of in generic Dictionary using foreach KeyValuePair

Tags: silverlight, dictionary, foreach, generics

In Silverlight3, when a generic Dictionary is iterated with foreach and a KeyValuePair, is the iteration guaranteed to visit the items in the dictionary in the order in which the items were added? That is, the iteration sequence has nothing to do with the key's datatype or its value? The documentation is less than explicit on this:

This code will produce output *similar* to the following:
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx
    (emphasis added)

```
Dictionary<String, Object> 
foreach (KeyValuePair String, Object kvp in myDictionary) {}

Dictionary<UInt16, String> 
foreach (KeyValuePair UInt16, String kvp in myDictionary) {}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iteration order depends on the key's hash codes and has nothing to do the the order in which they were added

Answer (score 2):

The spec for Dictionary says that the iteration order is undefined. So you shouldn't depend on it being anything.

The reality is that if you decompile the actual implementation using something like Reflector, you will see that it uses a backing array for the Values/Keys properties (with sentinels for removed items). The way this is implemented results in iteration in the order in which you added things. You're just not allowed to rely on that. I imagine there are a number of people unwittingly depending on such behaviour, though, so I doubt they'd change this any time soon. I still wouldn't want to rely on it for anything other than a quick one-off throwaway bit of code, though.

Answer (score 1):

I would not make code dependent on a specific sort order. If you need a collection/dictionary that iterates with a specific order, you should order it first (using the Linq OrderBy method). Even if your code is fine today, you might want to take advantage of the upcoming parallel execution of tasks, and then have to revisit the implementation details of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful replies.